# Seguimiento de fichero con tail -f

Tags: linux, bash, script

Estoy escribiendo el siguiente script *bash*:

```
#!/bin/bash

rm -fr *.log

# Primer programa, se ejecuta en bucle en segundo plano

./checker &

# Segundo programa, se ejecuta en bucle en segundo plano
# Redirecciono su salida a un log

./manager.py > manager.log &

sleep 1

# Tercer programa, se ejecuta en bucle en primer plano
# Utiliza la primera salida emitida por manager.py para ejecutarse
# Redirecciono su salida a un log

./processer.py "$(head -1 manager.log)" > processer.log
```

Me gustaría saber cómo mostrar el contenido de `manager.log` y `processer.log` cada vez que estos se actualizan.

He probado utilizando el comando `tail -f`, pero no funciona como esperaba, ya que únicamente muestra dicha información cuando interrumpo la ejecución de todos los procesos con Ctrl + C.

```
 #!/bin/bash

 rm -fr *.log

 ./checker &

 ./manager.py > manager.log &

 sleep 1

 ./processer.py "$(head -1 manager.log)" > processer.log &

 tail -f *.log
```

También me gustaría saber cómo puedo matar a todos los procesos cuando pulse Ctrl + C.

Comment: Lo suyo sería ejecutar el script en background y desde consola llamar a tail -f. De lo contrario, no creo que veas los resultados

Comment: Necesito ejecutar todo en un mismo script.

Comment: Probablemente el problema venga de que el script de Python no lanza los datos con periodicidad sino en bloques. Hice un script de prueba que lanza bien https://pastebin.com/94x9Fwh4

Comment: ¿Alguna forma de solucionarlo? Simplemente estoy redirigiendo prints.

Comment: ¿Cómo ejecutas tu script? ¿El tail lo haces después de que tu script esté corriendo o dentro del script?

Comment: Dentro del script, tal y como muestro en el código.

Comment: Coincido con el diagnostico de @fedorqui, revisa el código de `processer.py` si lo que direccionas es un `print`, prueba forzar el "flush" mediante `print("Hello world!", flush=True)`

Comment: Sí, de hecho estoy forzando el "flush" mediante `flush = true`. Pero igualmente lo único que muestra `tail -f` es la primera salida del programa y ninguna otra posterior.

Comment: Sin más datos es difícil de resolver. Tendríamos primero que ser capaces de reproducir el problema par luego encontrarle solución

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tiene que ver en el uso de los descriptores de archivo.

Cuando haces o siguiente:

```
./manager.py > manager.log &
```

Lo que haces es primero abrir el archivo `manager.log` en modo escritura pero no se escribe nada ahí hasta que termine el proceso que lleve acabo `manager.py`; si tienes corriendo, por ejemplo, un `while True`, tendrás que esperar a que acabe ese proceso: justamente, o nunca, o cuando envíes una señal de término (como `ctrl + C`).

Entonces, lo que puedes hacer es modificar tu código en python para:

1. Dentro del bucle (puede ser infinito) abrir y cerrar los descriptores de archivo haciendo uso de sentencias como `with open ...`
2. Ya sea restringir tu bucle a una cantidad finita de ciclos, algo que puedas predecir a los cuantos 'x' va a terminar para luego escribir.

Pongamos el primer caso

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import datetime

while True:  # Usando un bucle infinito
    time.sleep(2)
    with open('processer.log', 'a') as f: #  Aqui se abre y al final del bloque
                                          #+ se cierran los descriptores de archivo
                                          #+ escribiendo el contenido en el archivo.
        f.write("Dentro de processer.py, fecha: %s\n" % (datetime.datetime.now(),) )
```

En el segundo caso sería algo por el estilo:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import datetime

with open('processer.log', 'a') as f: # Abrimos el archivo en algun modo
    a = 0
    while a < 4: # Usamos un ciclo finito.
        f.write("Dentro de processer.py, fecha: %s\n" % (datetime.datetime.now(),) )
        a = a + 1
```

Después de alguno de estos, tu `tail -f *.log` debería correr sin problemas, a menos que, en el segundo caso, el ciclo sea muy grande: en ese caso tendrías que esperar el tiempo necesario en lo que acaba el proceso en tu código de python.

Ahora, para tu última pregunta referente a matar todos los procesos asociados cuando salgas del programa principal, se me ocurre que hagas una lista de los procesos en *background* y luego los "mates" cuando el programa principal reciba una señal. Para esto requeriremos de la función de `bash` que es `trap <funcion> señal1 señal2 ...`

Entonces tu código quedaría algo por el estilo:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a pids

clean() {
    kill ${pids[@]}  # Matamos todos los procesos en el array
}
# No recuerdo cuál señal es la exacta, puedes verlo en
#+man 7 signal, asi que use esas 4 que recordé.
#+Cuando el programa que estás corriendo reciba una señal, ya sea a causa
#+de un programa externo (como kill o htop, etc) o por la misma terminal,
#+(ya sea con un `ctrl + c` o `ctrl + z`) usará la función 
#+`clean` —previamente definida— para funcionar como manejador.
trap clean SIGINT SIGTERM EXIT SIGSTOP

touch {manager,processer}.log
tee *.log < /dev/null  # Esto es sólo para vaciar tus archivos de logs sin
                       #+necesidad de borrarlos y volverlos a crear.


./checker &
pids+=($!) #  El token "$!" sirve para traer el numero de proceso del ultimo programa
           #+ ejecutado en background. Lo estamos añadiendo al array de pids

python manager.py > manager.log &
pids+=($!)

python processer.py "$(head -1 manager.log)" > processer.log &
pids+=($!)

tail -f *.log
```

Y cuando presiones `ctrl + C`, cerrarás todos los procesos que se corrieron en background

Comment: Perfecto, era justo lo que quería saber. Como bien dices, sospechaba que el proceso se apropiaba del fichero y no lo liberaba hasta terminar su ejecución.  ¡Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

No sé si es esto lo que buscas, pero puede que te ayude, intenta esto para imprimir el tail en el proceso.

```
 #!/bin/bash

 rm -fr *.log

 ./checker &

 ./manager.py > manager.log &

 sleep 1

 ./processer.py "$(head -1 manager.log)" > processer.log &

 echo $(tail -n 10 *.log)
```

Comment: AP quiere ver tail _constantemente, de ahí la necesidad de `tail -f`

Comment: Efectivamente, necesito hacer un seguimiento continuo de los ficheros.